# How to implement zipWith N in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In my code, `zipWith7` works well but now the function in `zipWith7` require extra arity .

```
zipWith8 (\a b c d e f g h-> ....) List-A  ... List-H
```

while haskell base library only support up to 7 arity version.

Is there a way that can expand the function to N likr `zipWithN` ?

Comment: You can probably write it yourself easily enough.

Comment: What is the type of `zipWith`, `zipWith2`, `zipWith3`, etc.? What type would `zipWithN` have? Does this give any clues to whether or not a generalization is possible?

Comment: What does the `\a b c d e f g h -> ...` function do with the values? Could it operate on a list? [`transpose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) exists.

Comment: Forget these piddling complaints about types, I've got an even worse one: there's not even a coherent *behavior* to assign such a function. For example, what does `zipWithN id` do? Does it take one list, because `id :: a -> a` takes one argument, and return it without changing it, so `zipWithN id [] = []`, or does it take two lists, because `id :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)` takes two arguments, so `zipWithN id [] = \_ -> []`, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to do this (not that `zipWith8` and friends are really commonly needed!) is to make use of the [ZipList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) type and the `Applicative` operators.

```
zipWith8 f a b c d e f g h = getZipList $
  f <$> ZipList a
    <*> ZipList b
    <*> ZipList c
    <*> ZipList d
    <*> ZipList e
    <*> ZipList f
    <*> ZipList g
    <*> ZipList h
```

I'm sure you can figure out from this to write `zipWith9` etc if you wanted to.

Aside: this is mentioned in the [chapter of Learn You a Haskell dealing with Applicatives](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids):

> Aside from `zipWith`, the standard library has functions such as `zipWith3`, `zipWith4`, all the way up to 7. `zipWith` takes a function that takes two parameters and zips two lists with it. `zipWith3` takes a function that takes three parameters and zips three lists with it, and so on. By using zip lists with an applicative style, we don't have to have a separate zip function for each number of lists that we want to zip together. We just use the applicative style to zip together an arbitrary amount of lists with a function, and that's pretty cool.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a general function literally named `zipWithN` rather than having to write a separate function for each value of `N`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you could be right, and I stopped to consider that before posting this - but it's not 100% clear to me, and it's also not actually possible to write such a `zipWithN` (at least not without going deep into some type-level tricks that I'm not confident with). It's also not clear why one would ever need such a general function, so unless it's being asked simply as an academic exercise the OP would need to explain why they want such a function. I still thought this would be useful to the OP as is to show how to write this for any individual `N`.

Comment: Agreed. The question is ambiguous. And at least with an uncurried function we can't write a generalized `zipWithN`. If `zipWithN` takes a list of lists, then it is possible.

Comment: I'm not convinced that something like the type magic of printf is impossible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - me neither, which is why I added "(at least not without going deep into some type-level tricks...)"

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the first two lists to reduce the arity by one, if you also `uncurry` the function:

```
zipWithNplus1 f xs1 xs2 xs3 ... xsNplus1 =
   zipWithN (uncurry f) (zip xs1 xs2) xs3 ... xsNplus1
```

Otherwise, enable `ParallelListComp` and write a parallel list comprehension of any arity:

```
[ f x1 ... xN
| x1 <- xs1
| x2 <- xs2
| x3 <- xs3
...
| xN <- xsN
]
```

Comment: I don't think `...` is valid Haskell syntax. I assume you mean this is a place holder for `xs#` where `#` is an actual number, right? And we shouldn't take `xsNplus1` literally, either, right? So you are just showing the pattern in pseudocode about how to write each `zipWIthN` manually, but this isn't a generalized function that we can write once, which is what I think the OP is asking for.